# Transpose or Pivot - neo4j collect()

Tags: neo4j, cypher

**how to transpose a  n x m collection in the return statement ? OR before return statement based on a particular column?**

**example:**

A  | B | C

aa | 2 | 3

bb | 4 | 6

cc | 5 | 8

dd | 55| 9

**To**

aa  | bb |  cc | dd

2   | 4 |  5  | 55

3   |  6 |  8  | 9

**Example:**

with [{Label:'User',Lang:'English'},{Label:'Usuario',Lang:'Español'},{Label:'用户',Lang:'中文_简体'}] as t unwind t as p return

**this returns**

p.Label | p.Lang

User    | English

Usuario  | Español

用户    | 中文_简体

**should be transposed to**

User | Usuario | 用户

English |  Español | 中文_简体

Answer (score 0):

Well, MAYBE there is what you want in APOC.

```
CALL apoc.help(KEYWORD)
```

If not, you are good to write your own function

https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_user_defined_functions

Comment: Well, checked in APOC procedures list but didn't find keyword like transpose or pivot or example while googling.

Comment: so you are good for a List<List> to  List<List> converter.
So if you get N lines of 3 columns as input, you want 3 lines of N columns as output.
Beware, of the length of the input.

Answer (score 0):

Would *extract* help?  This might get you part-way there:

```
neo4j> with [{Label:'User',Lang:'English'},{Label:'Usuario',Lang:'Español'},{Label:'用户',Lang:'中文_简体'}] as t return extract( i in t | i.Label), extract(i in t | i.Lang);
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| extract( i in t | i.Label) | extract(i in t | i.Lang)        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| ["User", "Usuario", "用户"]  | ["English", "Español", "中文_简体"] |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I need in 2d matrix form...Guess, we would have to write custom procedure..